# Set coupon code used for customer in Magento

Tags: magento, coupon

I'm integrating a system with Magento.

When I create an order, if my non-Magento system indicates the order does have a coupon I would like to mark the coupon code as "used" for that customer, so the next time he tries to use it, Magento will know that customer already used it.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to do it like this:

```
 $coupon = mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($code, 'code');
 $coupon->setTimesUsed($coupon->getTimesUsed()+1);
 $coupon->save();

 $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($coupon->getRuleId());
 $rule->setTimesUsed($rule->getTimesUsed()+1);
 $rule->save();


 $couponUsage = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_usage');
 $couponUsage->updateCustomerCouponTimesUsed($customerId,$coupon->getCouponId());
```

Thanks to this post:
[Magento - Single Coupon marked as used when payment pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268938/magento-single-coupon-marqued-as-used-when-payment-pending)

Comment: What if guest user consumed it?

Comment: do not forget of $ruleUsageModel = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_customer');
                      $ruleUsage = $ruleUsageModel->loadByCustomerRule($order->getCustomerId(), $rule->getId());

Answer (score 0):

Set the Shopping Cart Rule's `Uses per Customer` to 1.

----EDIT----

If you want to apply the coupon in your code then you can do something like this:

```
$coupon_code = "YOUR_CODE";

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
    ->getQuote()
    ->setCouponCode($coupon_code)
    ->collectTotals()
    ->save();
```

Comment: Right but, in code, how do I set the code as used by a customer?

Comment: I'm confused by the question a bit.  Are you redeeming the coupon?  See my answer edit above.

Comment: Thanks seanbreeen. However this situation will not work for my case because I don't create a cart in Magento for said customer, I receive the cart info from another system and I just create the order in Magento. What I'm trying to achieve is when I create the order set that coupon as used by said customer